# How can I have a server fetch a JSON file every few seconds?

Tags: linux, json, shell, cron, hosting

I have access to a third-party JSON file that contains about 1MB of real-time information, and the file updates constantly. My website will display and update this information every few seconds. I can't have the users access the JSON directly from the source, because my access key will be revoked for excessive use. So I need to copy the JSON file to a server every few seconds, and have users get the JSON from that server.

How should I get a server to do this? (I don't have my own server.) CRON jobs can only run every minute at most. Should I have a shell script make a copy of this file every x seconds? Can a shell script really run forever? Maybe I should have a CRON job execute a shell script?

I've also looked at cloud data hosting, but with 1MB being pulled even just every 20 seconds by each user, I could quickly go through gigabytes of data transfer, which can cost hundreds of dollars a month with these services. Unless you know of a data host that's cheaper.

Comment: Can't you design things differently? Transmit only differences? Have something else than a JSON file? Compress it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take a look at [The Fat Controller](http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net) which can daemonise and repeat anything.   So you could create your shell script to copy the JSON data and have the Fat Controller run it every few seconds.   It also has behaviour to handle if the script fails.   There's more information including full documentation and example use-cases on the website:

http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net